# Can I place a window inside a window? Like a videoplayer

Tags: windows, visual-c++, opencv, win32gui

I'm using C++(Visual Studio 10) on Windows XP.

I want to make an application similar to a video player where there is a window inside an outer window where the actual video is displayed. On the outer window I will have the GUI, buttons, etc...

Basically I'm composing two windows together. And the frames in the inner window are updated by another thread that does image processing(I will use OpenCV for this).

Any pointers? I just need to know the basic structure for this.

Comment: Have you worked with the Windows API before? Creating child windows (which is what you're describing) is a fundamental and common task, so I'm inclined to think that you have little or no experience with the Windows API.

Comment: You are 100% right, that's why I'm asking the question ;)

Comment: Ok then, one step at a time. So your question becomes how to create a window inside another window using win32. In that case, this is an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838511/how-should-i-create-a-child-window-in-win32-while-programming-with-c

Answer (score 1):

Build the entire GUI using win32 and then convert the IplImage to BITMAP to be able to display it. It seems someone posted a [quick and dirty solution](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Convert-IplImage-to-Bitmap-td3784378.html) to do that, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Apparently the server from the link just crashed. While they don't fix the problem, this is the cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XZ6ghXR-gBUJ:opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Convert-IplImage-to-Bitmap-td3784378.html+Convert-IplImage-to-Bitmap-td3784378&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu